# Infernal Three in Chilling Adventures of Sabrina

Tags: character, the-chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

Who were the **Three Judges** in **Chilling Adventures of Sabrina** (Part 1 Episode 3) ?

[image: three judges]
[image: Blind]

Are they **Blind**? And how much **power** do they have as their decision is binding over the **Devil** itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of Justice itself has often been represented by the personification of a lady wearing a blindfold. The blindfold itself represents impartiality, the ideal that justice should be applied without regard to wealth, power, or other status. The same rule applies for both Greeks and Trojans.

[image: The Justice, in front of the Supreme Court of Brazil]

The *Justice*, in front of the Supreme Court of Brazil ([source](http://www.museuvirtualbrasil.com.br/museu_brasilia/uploads/photos/167.jpg))

The idea of Three Judges is pretty common in Greek mythology.

According with the Greek Underworld, there are three judges of the dead: Minos, Rhadamanthus and Aeacus.

[image: Minos, Aiakos and Rhadamanthys]

They judge the heart of each soul that enters the Underworld. Souls deemed righteous were allowed to enter the Elysium Fields, while souls deemed as being evil were sentenced to the depths of Tartarus. They were the sons of Zeus and Europa.

[These judges were also represented on the video game God of War III](https://godofwar.fandom.com/wiki/The_Three_Judges).

Comment: what about the power they possess as they can decide over matters of gods.

Comment: @rishabhagarwal I don't believe we have an "in-universe" answer yet. So far episode 3 just shows them presiding over matters at the Infernal trail, but it has yet to either establish the full inner workings of the Infernal Court (ie: how people may get appointed to positions) and/or what exact supernatural powers are that come with the judge role(s). The only thing we know there is a door to hell that one, such as the high priest and Sabrina's lawyer can discuss terms with Satan.